# How to wrap around a range

Tags: c++, range

Angles in my program are expressed in 0 to 2pi. I want a way to add two angles and have it wrap around the 2pi to 0 if the result is higher than 2pi. Or if I subtracted an angle from an angle and it was below 0 it would wrap around 2pi.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633177/c-how-to-wrap-a-float-to-the-interval-pi-pi/4635752#4635752

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What you are looking for is the modulus. The fmod function will not work because it calculates the remainder and not the arithmetic modulus. Something like this should work:

```
inline double wrapAngle( double angle )
{
    double twoPi = 2.0 * 3.141592865358979;
    return angle - twoPi * floor( angle / twoPi );
}
```

Edit:

The remainder is commonly defined as what is left over after long division (eg. the remainder of 18/4 is 2, because **18 = 4 * 4 + 2**). This gets hairy when you have negative numbers. The common way to find the remainder of a signed division is for the remainder to have the same sign as the result (eg. the remainder of -18/4 is -2, because **-18 = -4 * 4 + -2**).

The definition of x modulus y is the smallest positive value of m in the equation x=y*c+m, given c is an integer. So **18 mod 4** would be 2 (where c=4), however **-18 mod 4** would also be 2 (where c=-5).

The simplest calculation of **x mod y** is **x-y*floor(x/y)**, where floor is the largest integer that is less than or equal to the input.

Comment: I just want to add that this is useful on platforms where there is no fmod or it is slow. Note that your could replace "angle / twoPi" by "angle * (1.0 / 2.0*3.141592865358979)", if divisions are slow on your platform. If you need or can do with a normalized result afterwards, use "return angle - floor(angle  * (1.0 / 2.0*3.141592865358979))", which brings the result into [0, 1], or "return angle - floor(angle  * (1.0 / 2.0*3.141592865358979) - 0.5)" for a range of [-0.5, 0.5]. Also note that this is well-suited for fixed-point calculations too.

Answer (score 12):

Out of curiosity, I experimented with three algorithms in other answers, timing them.

When the values to be normalized are close to the range 0..2π, then the `while` algorithm is quickest; the algorithm using `fmod()` is slowest, and the algorithm using `floor()` is in between.

When the values to be normalized are not close to the range 0..2π, then the `while` algorithm is slowest, the algorithm using `floor()` is quickest, and the algorithm using `fmod()` is in between.

So, I conclude that:

- If the angles are (generally) close to normalized, the `while` algorithm is the one to use.
- If the angles are not close to normalized, then the `floor()` algorithm is the one to use.

#### Test results:

r1 = `while`, r2 = `fmod()`, r3 = `floor()`

```
Near Normal     Far From Normal
r1 0.000020     r1 0.000456
r2 0.000078     r2 0.000085
r3 0.000058     r3 0.000065
r1 0.000032     r1 0.000406
r2 0.000085     r2 0.000083
r3 0.000057     r3 0.000063
r1 0.000033     r1 0.000406
r2 0.000085     r2 0.000085
r3 0.000058     r3 0.000065
r1 0.000033     r1 0.000407
r2 0.000086     r2 0.000083
r3 0.000058     r3 0.000063
```

#### Test code:

The test code used the value shown for `PI`.  The C standard does not define a value for π, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html) does define `M_PI` and a number of related constants, so I could have written my code using `M_PI` instead of `PI`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "timer.h"

static const double PI = 3.14159265358979323844;

static double r1(double angle)
{
    while (angle > 2.0 * PI)
        angle -= 2.0 * PI;
    while (angle < 0)
        angle += 2.0 * PI;
    return angle;
}

static double r2(double angle)
{
    angle = fmod(angle, 2.0 * PI);
    if (angle < 0.0)
        angle += 2.0 * PI;
    return angle;
}

static double r3(double angle)
{
    double twoPi = 2.0 * PI;
    return angle - twoPi * floor( angle / twoPi );
}

static void tester(const char * tag, double (*test)(double), int noisy)
{
    typedef struct TestSet { double start, end, increment; } TestSet;
    static const TestSet tests[] =
    {
        {   -6.0 * PI,   +6.0 * PI, 0.01 },
    //  { -600.0 * PI, +600.0 * PI, 3.00 },
    };
    enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
    {
        for (double angle = tests[i].start; angle < tests[i].end; angle += tests[i].increment)
        {
            double result = (*test)(angle);
            if (noisy)
                printf("%12.8f : %12.8f\n", angle, result);
        }
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("%s %s\n", tag, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
}

int main(void)
{
    tester("r1", r1, 0);
    tester("r2", r2, 0);
    tester("r3", r3, 0);
    tester("r1", r1, 0);
    tester("r2", r2, 0);
    tester("r3", r3, 0);
    tester("r1", r1, 0);
    tester("r2", r2, 0);
    tester("r3", r3, 0);
    tester("r1", r1, 0);
    tester("r2", r2, 0);
    tester("r3", r3, 0);
    return(0);
}
```

Testing on Mac OS X 10.7.4 with the standard `/usr/bin/gcc` (`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)`).  The 'close to normalized' test code is shown; the 'far from normalized' test data was created by uncommenting the `//` comment in the test data.

Timing with a home-built GCC 4.7.1 is similar (the same conclusions would be drawn):

```
Near Normal     Far From Normal
r1 0.000029     r1 0.000321
r2 0.000075     r2 0.000094
r3 0.000054     r3 0.000065
r1 0.000028     r1 0.000327
r2 0.000075     r2 0.000096
r3 0.000053     r3 0.000068
r1 0.000025     r1 0.000327
r2 0.000075     r2 0.000101
r3 0.000053     r3 0.000070
r1 0.000028     r1 0.000332
r2 0.000076     r2 0.000099
r3 0.000050     r3 0.000065
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
while (angle > 2pi)
    angle -= 2pi;

while (angle < 0)
    angle += 2pi;
```

Basically, you have to change the angle by 2pi until you are assured that it doesn't exceed 2pi or fall below 0.

Comment: Works and makes sense, but could be pretty inefficient.

Comment: If the input angle is a long ways from normalized, this can not only be inefficient, but produce fairly inaccurate results.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case there are some efficient special cases if you have the luxury of choosing your own representation of an angle. (Note that having 0 as the lower bound is already a special case allowing for efficiency.)

### Expressing angles as unit vectors

If you are able to represent angles as values between [0 and 1) instead of [0 and 2π) then you merely need to take the fractional part:

```
float wrap(float angle) {
    // wrap between [0 and 2*PI)
    return angle - floor(angle);
}
```

Negative angles just work.

You can also normalize, wrap, then scale back to radians with some loss of precision and efficiency.

This can be useful in code that works similar to a lot of shader code, and especially in an "everything is a unit vector" environment.

### Expressing angles as unsigned integers limited at a power of two

If you are able to represent angles as values between [0 and 2^n) instead of [0 and 2π) then you can wrap them to within a power of two with a bitwise and operation:

```
unsigned int wrap(unsigned int angle) {
    // wrap between [0 and 65,535)
    return angle & 0xffff;
}
```

Even better, if you can choose a power of two that's equal to the size of an integer type, the numbers just wrap naturally. A `uint16_t` always wraps to within [0 and 2^16) and a `uint32_t` always wraps to within [0 and 2^32). Sixty five thousand headings should be enough for anyone right? (-:

I used this in game and demo type things in the 8-bit days and even for texture mapping before 3D graphics cards. I suppose it would still be useful in code for emulators and retrogaming but perhaps even on tiny microcontrollers?

Answer (score 1):

Simple trick: Just add an offset, which must be a *multiple* of 2pi, to bring the result into a positive range prior to doing the fmod(). The fmod() will bring it back into the range [0, 2pi) automagically. This works as long as you know a priori the range of possible inputs you might get (which you often do). The larger the offset you apply, the more bits of FP precision you loose, so you probably don't want to add, say, 20000pi, although that would certainly be "safer" in terms of handling very large out-of-bounds inputs. Presuming no one would ever pass input angles that sum outside the rather crazy range [-8pi, +inf), we'll just add 8pi before fmod()ing.

```
double add_angles(float a, float b)
{
    ASSERT(a + b >= -8.0f*PI);
    return fmod(a + b + 8.0f*PI, 2.0f*PI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likewise if you want to be in the range -2pi to 2pi then fmod works great

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and fast enough:

```
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846    
#endif // !M_PI
#ifndef M_2PI
#define M_2PI (2.0 * M_PI)
#endif // !M_2PI
#define to0_2pi(x) ((x) - ((int)((x) / (M_2PI)) - signbit(x)) * (M_2PI))
```