# How can I make this function timing macro work in C?

Tags: c, time, macros

From a comment to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/459704/2812104

I tried to make a macro function that takes a function as argument and times it using `clock()`. However I keep getting an error message saying that `start` is undeclared and I can't figure it out since I do declare it earlier in the macro

(this is all on the same line in my code in case it makes a difference; I'm breaking it up in two lines here for readability):

```
#define timing(a): clock_t start = clock(); a; clock_t stop = clock(); 
printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: You don't want the colon in `timing(a):` (or, if you keep it, you have to use `label timing(function(1, 2, 3));` so you have a label for the colon).  And it matters whether it is on one logical line — you should continue the line with a backslash so it is clearer what you're doing.  I'm not convinced that's a good macro to be using.

Comment: In addition, if you plan to use the macro in more than one place in your program, enclose it in `{}`, or else you will have multiple instances of `stop` and `start`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank you it worked, but why do you say it might not be a good macro to be using?

Comment: @DYZ, do you mean { timing(function()) } every time I use it, or enclose the definition of the macro itself in curly braces? Also if you don't mind, what do you mean by multiple instances? I mostly think of instances in the context of OOP, which is probably not what you mean, right?

Comment: Enclose the macro definition in `{}`. Otherwise, you may have `clock_t start; .... clock_t start; ....`, which is illegal. With the braces, each variable is declared within its own block: `{clock_t start; ....} {clock_t start; ....}`

Comment: My discomfort arises from what you're going to use as the argument to the macro. A simple function call is OK. Making it a loop or more complex is theoretically feasible, but not necessarily a good idea (so `timing(for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) some_func(i, i * 10, i + 10);)` starts to feel uncomfortable). More protracted code in the argument gets less and less comfortable. Your decision — if you fix it as suggested, it is usable, but be cautious. (I'd probably aim at higher-precision timers than `clock()` — and therefore I prefer a functional interface to deal with system idiosyncrasies.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. It seems all of this reinvention-of-the-wheel could be avoided by *just using a profiler*...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank you for explaining. What would you recommend as a higher-precision timer?

Comment: It depends on the o/s — which is why it needs to be hidden.  If it's available, `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` gives you nanosecond resolution (but not necessarily nanosecond precision).  If that's not available, maybe `gettimeofday()` is available (microsecond resolution), or `ftime()` (millisecond resolution) or `clock()` as you're using (resolution system-dependent), or `times()` (resolution system-dependent), or `GetTickCount()`, or … hey, it's fun being fussy.  Using `clock()` is mostly portable, but the resolution you get isn't necessarily very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is the colon after `timing(a)` — that wants a label to precede it, but you can't use labels on variable definitions, so you need to lose the colon:

```
#define timing(a) \
    clock_t start = clock(); \
    a; \
    clock_t stop = clock(); \
    printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

You should probably also avoid polluting the function's name space.  The classic way to do that is a `do { … } while (0)` loop:

```
#define timing(a) \
    do { \
        clock_t start = clock(); \
        a; \
        clock_t stop = clock(); \
        printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC); \
    } while (0)
```

This creates a statement block that can be used legitimately even in an unprotected `if` block:

```
if (do_it_this_way)
    timing(some_func(1, 37, 91));
else
    timing(some_func(2, 41, 87));
```

If you use just `{ … }` around the macro body, this generates an error (because the semicolon after `91` means the else doesn't belong to any `if` — the expansion is `if (do_it_this_way) { … }; else …`).

I'm not particularly keen on this technique.  I use a logically opaque type, `Clock`, with support functions such as:

```
extern void  clk_init(Clock *clk);
extern void  clk_start(Clock *clk);
extern void  clk_stop(Clock *clk);
extern char *clk_elapsed_ms(Clock *clk, char *buffer, size_t buflen);
extern char *clk_elapsed_us(Clock *clk, char *buffer, size_t buflen);
extern char *clk_elapsed_ns(Clock *clk, char *buffer, size_t buflen);
```

The calling code creates and initializes a `Clock`, and can then start the clock before the loop, stop the clock after it, and at its leisure analyze the elapsed time.  You can find this code on Github https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq in `timer.c` and `timer.h`.  You can find examples of it being used if you search on SO with the term '`user:15168 clk_elapsed_us`' (e.g. [How to wrap around a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980292/how-to-wrap-around-a-range/11980755#11980755)).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this is very helpful.