# The "infinite" increase/decrease in an angle

Tags: c++, geometry

I need to increase/reduce **phi** angle by value **d** infinitely. (**d** can be negative or positive).

"Infinitely" means that cycling change can happen as much as long. But to avoid overflowing it is necessary "drop" value, relying on periodicity of sin () and cos (). (0 <=> 2*pi <=> 2*n*pi).

How it can be implemented in function? (e.g. double stepAngle(double phi, double d)).

Comment: modular arithmetic might be helpful

Comment: @thiton The homework tag should never be used: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633177/c-how-to-wrap-a-float-to-the-interval-pi-pi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to renormalize to the desired range:

```
while (d > 2*pi) d -= 2*pi;
while (d < 0) d += 2*pi;
```

That will be efficient as long as `d` is not extremely far outside the range of 0..2*pi.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library functions just "do the right thing" for values > 2*pi, you don't have to do anything:

```
int main() {
  double pi = 3.14159265359;
  double x = 2.5;
  cout << sin(x) << endl;
  cout << sin(x + 2*pi) << endl;
  cout << sin(x - 8*pi) << endl;
}
```

These will all print the same value; try it out.

Comment: I know it. But if a value of an angle increases "infinitely", there is an overflowing sooner or later. Therefore I ask this question.

Comment: Also as one gets further and further away from 0, there is a loss of precision because the number of bits used for the mantissa is finite.  If you have a number like 3000000000000 and add 0.001 (using an IEEE double), the result is still 3000000000000.  If you add 0.01 instead, that change can be represented within the available precision.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with `fmod` fairly easily.

```
 double stepAngle(double phi, double d)
 {
    double newPhi = phi += fmod(2*pi, d);
    if(newPhi > 2*pi)
    {
      newPhi -= 2*pi;
    }
    if(newPhi < 0)
    {
      newPhi += 2*pi;
    }

    return newPhi;
```