# Trouble understanding Caesar decryption steps

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, caesar-cipher

The following code will decrypt a caesar encrypted string given the ciphertext and the key:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string decrypt(std::string cipher, int key) {
    std::string d = "";
    for(int i=0; i<cipher.length();i++) {
        d += ((cipher[i]-65-key+26) %26)+65;
    }
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << decrypt("WKLVLVJRRG", 3) << std::endl; // THISISGOOD
    std::cout << decrypt("NBCMCMAIIX", 20) << std::endl; // THISISGOOD
}
```

I'm having trouble to understand the operations performed to compute the new character ASCII code at this line:

```
d += ((cipher[i]-65-key+26) %26)+65;
```

1. The first subtraction should shift the number range
2. Then we will subtract the key as how the Caesar decryption is defined
3. We add 26 to deal with negative numbers (?)
4. The module will limit the output as the range of the ASCII numbers is 26 length
5. We come back to the old range by adding 65 at the end

What am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to guess what knowledge you may be missing, but perhaps of note - the `%` operator does not behave the same as the mathematical concept of "modulo", when used on a negative value.  The line of code you are asking about has added complexity to make it less likely that `%26` is operated on a negative number.

Comment: The code is working fine though. What I am missing are the intuition about the numbers

Comment: Again, guessing what you don't know because "What am I missing?" is **not** a clear question.  Perhaps you don't know that `65` is the ASCII value for the capital letter `A`.  And `26` is the number of letters in the ASCII alphabet.  Those are the two numbers used in the code you are asking about.

Comment: Or if you are unsure of the algorithm here, look at [Clean, efficient algorithm for wrapping integers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707370/clean-efficient-algorithm-for-wrapping-integers-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we reorder the expression slightly, like this:

```
d += (((cipher[i] - 65) + (26 - key)) % 26) + 65;
```

We get a formula for *rotating* `cipher[i]` *left* by `key`:

- `cipher[i] - 65` brings the ASCII range `A`..`Z` into an integer range 0..25
- `(cipher[i] - 65 + 26 - key) % 26` rotates that value left by `key` (subtracts `key` modulo 26)
- `+ 65` to shift the range 0..25 back into ASCII range `A`..`Z`.

e.g. given a `key` of 2, `A` becomes `Y`, `B` becomes `Z`, `C` becomes `A`, etc.

Comment: what `(26 - key)` indicates?

Comment: `(26 - key)` is -key mod 26

Comment: 26 corresponds to the modulus of the operation. Imagine a circle of size 26, you can go left N steps or right 26-N steps and you arrive at the same location. So `26-key` is equivalent to `-key` in the modulo 26 space, with the added benefit of being non-negative. We need to remain non-negative because `%` doesn't yield a modulus with a negative input.

Comment: So I suppose that is code is not going to work for keys > 26

Comment: Yes that's correct. But it's also not needed, as the rotation would repeat for any value >26.

Comment: What you mean that is not needed? If you have, let's say, `key = 150` how do you manage to get the right index?

Comment: The prerequisite of this encryption is that key is in range 1..25. Keys above 25 are meaningless and not supposed to be used.

Comment: Suppose that key > 26, how would you fix the above code? Is a `key = 150` to be considered 6 or 20?

Comment: _"how would you fix the above code?"_  Again, see [Clean, efficient algorithm for wrapping integers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707370/clean-efficient-algorithm-for-wrapping-integers-in-c).  The accepted answer there does it correctly.  Your code is subtracting the `key` and then wrapping, with a "lower bound" of `'A'` and an "upper bound" of `'Z'`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a detailed explanation about Caesar Cipher for understanding that formular.  I will also show ultra simple code examples, but also more advanced one liners.

The biggest problems are potential overflows. So, we need to deal with that.

Then we need to understand what Encryption and decryption means. If encryption will shift everthing one to the right, decryption will shift it back to left again.

- So, with "def" and key=1, the encrpyted string will be "efg".
- And decrpytion with key=1, will shift it to left again. Result: "def"

We can observe that we simply need to shift by -1, so the negative of the key.

So, basically encryption and decryption can be done with the **same routine**. We just need to invert the keys.

Let us look now at the overflow problematic. For the moment we will start with uppercase characters only. Characters have an associated code. For example, in ASCII, the letter 'A' is encoded with 65, 'B' with 66 and so on. Because we do not want to calculate with such number, we normalize them. We simply subtract 'A' from each character. Then

- 'A' - 'A' = 0
- 'B' - 'A' = 1
- 'C' - 'A' = 2
- 'D' - 'A' = 3

You see the pattern. If we want to encrypt now the letter 'C' with key 3, we can do the following.

'C' - 'A' + 3 = 5  Then we add again 'A' to get back the letter and we will get 5 + 'A' = 'F'

That is the whole magic.

But what to do with an overflow, beyond 'Z'. This can be handled by a simple modulo division.

Let us look at 'Z' + 1. We do 'Z' - 'A' = 25, then +1 = 26 and now modulo 26 = 0 then plus 'A' will be 'A'

And so on and so on. The resulting Formula is: (c-'A'+key)%26+'A'

Next, what with negative keys? This is also simple. Assume an 'A' and key=-1

Result will be a 'Z'. But this is the same as shifting 25 to the right. So, we can simply convert a negative key to a positive shift. The simple statement will be:

```
if (key < 0)  key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;
```

And then we can call our tranformation function with a simple Lambda. One function for encryption and decrytion. Just with an inverted key.

And with the above formular, there is even no need to check for a negative values. It will work for positive and negative values.

So, `key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;` will always work.

---

Some extended information, if you work with ASCII character representation. Please have a look at any ASCII table. You will see that any uppercase and lowercase character differ by 32. Or, if you look in binary:

```
char  dez  bin           char  dez  bin
'A'   65   0100 0001     'a'   97   0110 0001 
'B'   66   0100 0010     'b'   98   0110 0010 
'C'   67   0100 0011     'b'   99   0110 0011 
 . . .
```

So, if you already know that a character is alpha, then the only difference between upper- and lowercase is bit number 5. If we want to know, if `char`  is lowercase, we can get this by masking this bit. `c & 0b0010 0000` that is equal to `c & 32` or `c & 0x20`.

If we want to operater on either uppercase or lowercase characters, the we can mask the "case" away. With `c & 0b00011111` or `c & 31` or `c & 0x1F` we will get always equivalents for uppercase charcters, already normalized to start with one.

```
char  dez  bin        Masking         char  dez  bin         Masking
'A'   65   0100 0001  & 0x1b = 1      'a'   97   0110 0001   & 0x1b = 1
'B'   66   0100 0010  & 0x1b = 2      'b'   98   0110 0010   & 0x1b = 2
'C'   67   0100 0011  & 0x1b = 3      'b'   99   0110 0011   & 0x1b = 3
 . . .
```

So, if we use an alpha character, mask it, and subtract 1, then we get as a result 0..25 for any upper- or lowercase character.

---

Additionally, I would like tor repeat the key handling. Positive keys will encrypt a string, negative keys will decrypt a string. But, as said above, negative keys can be transormed into positive ones. Example:

```
Shifting by  -1  is same as shifting by  +25
Shifting by  -2  is same as shifting by  +24
Shifting by  -3  is same as shifting by  +23
Shifting by  -4  is same as shifting by  +22
```

So,it is very obvious that we can calculate an always positive key by: `26 + key`. For negative keys, this will give us the above offsets.

And for positve keys, we would have an overflow over 26, which we can elimiate by a modulo 26 division:

```
'A'-->  0 + 26 = 26    26 % 26 = 0 
'B'-->  1 + 26 = 27    27 % 26 = 1 
'C'-->  2 + 26 = 28    28 % 26 = 2 
'D'-->  3 + 26 = 29    29 % 26 = 3
```

--> `(c + key) % 26` will eliminate overflows and result in the correct new en/decryptd character.

And, if we combine this with the above wisdom for negative keys, we can write: `((26+(key%26))%26)` which will work for all positive and negative keys.

Combining that with that masking, could give us the following program:

```
const char potentialLowerCaseIndicator = c & 0x20;
const char upperOrLower = c & 0x1F;
const char normalized = upperOrLower - 1;
const int withOffset =  normalized + ((26+(key%26))%26);
const int withOverflowCompensation = withOffset % 26;
const char newUpperCaseCharacter = (char)withOverflowCompensation + 'A';
const char result = newUpperCaseCharacter | (potentialLowerCaseIndicator );
```

Of course, all the above many statements can be converted into one Lambda:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

// Simple function for Caesar encyption/decyption

std::string caesar(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');

    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), [&](char c) {return std::isalpha(c) ? (char)((((c & 31) - 1 + ((26 + (key % 26)) % 26)) % 26 + 65) | (c & 32)) : c; });

    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::string test{ "aBcDeF xYzZ" };
    std::cout << caesar(test, 5);
}
```

---

The last function can also be made more verbose for easier understanding:

```
std::string caesar1(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');

    auto convert = [&](const char c) -> char {
        char result = c;
        if (std::isalpha(c)) {

            // Handling of a negative key (Shift to left). Key will be converted to positive value
            if (key < 0) {
                // limit the key to 0,-1,...,-25
                key = key % 26;
                // Key was negative: Now we have someting between 0 and 26
                key = 26 + key;
            };

            // Check and remember if the original character was lower case
            const bool originalIsLower = std::islower(c);

            // We want towork with uppercase only
            const char upperCaseChar = (char)std::toupper(c);

            // But, we want to start with 0 and not with 'A' (65)
            const int normalized = upperCaseChar - 'A';

            // Now add the key
            const int shifted = normalized + key;

            // Addition result maybe bigger then 25, so overflow. Cap it
            const int capped = shifted % 26;

            // Get back a character
            const char convertedUppcase = (char)capped + 'A';

            // And set back the original case
            result = originalIsLower ? (char)std::tolower(convertedUppcase) : convertedUppcase;
        }
        return result;
    };
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), convert);
    return res;
}
```

---

And if you want to see a solution with only the simplest  statements, then see the below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string caesar(string in, int key) {

    // Here we will store the resulting encrypted/decrypted string
    string result{};


    // Handling of a negative key (Shift to left). Key will be converted to positive value
    if (key < 0) {
        // limit the key to 0,-1,...,-25
        key = key % 26;
        // Key was negative: Now we have someting between 0 and 26
        key = 26 + key;
    };
   
    // Read character by character from the string
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i) {

        char c = in[i];

        // CHeck for alpha character
        if ((c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z') or (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z')) {

            // Check and remember if the original character was lower case
            bool originalIsLower = (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z');

            // We want to work with uppercase only
            char upperCaseChar = originalIsLower ? c - ('a' - 'A') : c;

            // But, we want to start with 0 and not with 'A' (65)
            int normalized = upperCaseChar - 'A';

            // Now add the key
            int shifted = normalized + key;

            // Addition result maybe bigger then 25, so overflow. Cap it
            int capped = shifted % 26;

            // Get back a character
            char convertedUppcase = (char)capped + 'A';

            // And set back the original case
            result += originalIsLower ? convertedUppcase + ('a' - 'A') : convertedUppcase;

        }
        else
            result += c;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    string test{ "aBcDeF xYzZ" };
    string encrypted = caesar(test, 5);
    string decrypted = caesar(encrypted, -5);

    cout << "Original:  " << test << '\n';
    cout << "Encrpyted: " << encrypted << '\n';
    cout << "Decrpyted: " << decrypted << '\n';
}
```